# songs list under albums is absent in new ios 8.4 music app

Tags: iphone, ios, music

Before update, when i was viewing artists and I'd go inside an artist, I could see an album name followed by all songs under that album and then the next album and so on.

Now, in artist view, I just see the album and I have to go further inside to see the songs of that album (unless there is just one song in the album).

Is this bothering someone else? Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: If the artist has 3 or more albums, it then only shows the Albums and you have to go further to see the songs, but if the artist has less than that, it shows the songs under the album just like before. I believe there is nothing you can do about that as it's the apps configuration. You can however post a review on it. ;)

Comment: I don't see any logic to different functionalities based on number of albums.
But thanks, what you say is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it depends on how many songs/albums you have for each artist. Some artists that I have only a few songs from have the same old style. If I have like every song from every album, then I have your problem. I think it just depends on the amount of songs you have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it depends on how many albums you have.

If you have a lot of albums from an artist with only a couple of songs on each album, it's a truly awful piece of UX design.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I prefer it like this as this is how it used to be... I was a bit confused to why it was only doing it with some and not others but now I understand having it not bunch them up if I only have two or less albums is a lot more bearable than if for example, I have ten albums of some artists and have to go through every single song to get to one album. Much better for those that have a large music collection!